no matching function for call to 'getline and c_cpp_properties.json, problems with the setup?
I'm trying to learn C++ in VSCode but I keep finding issues and I don't know where this one is coming from. As I try to run it, I get the error "no matching function for call to 'getline" and several errors coming from the c_cpp_properties.json file:
enter image description here
This is the code:
enter image description here
And this is the json file:
enter image description here
Maybe I've done something wrong on the set up, I followed this website to guide me:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw
then I also added the Paths in the json file, but it doesnt seem to work, could anyone help me?

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please never share code as a screenshot, but as text.

Put commas after each path in the includePath property

Of course it was that simple, thank you very much gentleman
